# MyBatis and ClassCastException with List

Tags: java, mybatis

Here is my request method for getting some entities from my DB:

1. Xml

   select * from client_access
            where client_id = #{clientId}
                and partner = #{partner}
            
                and auto_renewal = #{autoRenewal}
            
            order by id

2. Interface

   List findByClientAndPartnerWithAutoRenewal(@Param("clientId") Long clientId,
   @Param("partner") String partner,
   @Param("autoRenewal") Boolean autoRenewal);
3. Class (it's line number 70 from the stacktrace)

   final List clientAccesses = tokenService.findByClientAndPartnerWithAutoRenewal(client, IVI_CODE, true);
   if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(clientAccesses)) {
   taskDetail.setStatus(DetailStatus.SUCCESS);
   taskDetail.setExtSysResultId(NO_AUTO_RENEW_TOKEN_MESSAGE);
   }

I'm getting exception only when my app starts:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class myapp.bundle.core.model.entity.client.ClientAccess cannot be cast to class java.util.List (myapp.bundle.core.model.entity.client.ClientAccess is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @4520ebad; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at myapp.bundle.service.security.impl.TokenServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f8982ea2.findByClientAndPartnerWithAutoRenewal(<generated>)
    at myapp.bundle.service.bundle.impl.ivi.IviCancelService.cancelIviAutoRenew(IviCancelService.java:70)
```

What can be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

the return object of this method is not correct from what I read in the error findByClientAndPartnerWithAutoRenewal, it does not return a list, it returns an object myapp.bundle.core.model.entity.client.ClientAccess.